# JavaFX: Create custom data attributes for nodes

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am currently in need of custom attributes which I can fetch anytime. Is there any way to create custom data attributes for nodes and then get those values in javafx?

Lets assume I have the the follwing Button.

```
<Button text="Im a button" fooBar="I hold some value" />
```

Similar to: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Now in HTML I could simply do the following:

```
<div id="example" data-foobar="I hold some value"></div>
```

Then I could easily get the data like this:

```
document.getElementById("example").dataset.foobar;
```

**Edit:** I need more than 1 data property for a node because a node can hold various information.

Comment: what about using `userData`?

Comment: Can we have more than 1 user data though?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The data can be stored in [the `properties` `ObservableMap` of a `Node`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getProperties--)

```
Node node = ...
node.getProperties().put("foo", "bar");
...
Object foo = node.getProperties().get("foo");
```

Note however that some layout properties use this map too, so no property names similar to javafx properties / "static" properties should be used as key. To be sure you could create a custom key class that does not return `true` if an object of another type is passed as parameter to `equals`.

Comment: Looks like a better answer. Accepted

Answer (score 4):

To solve your problem you should to use `userData` it can be any object that you need.

```
node.setUserData("Hello world");
node2.setUserData(123);
```

etc.

If you need to set multiple values you can save your values in an array, list, json etc.

```
ArrayList<String> vals = new ArrayList();
vals.add("Hello");
vals.add("World");
node3.setUserData(vals);
//some code
ArrayList<String> result = (ArrayList) node3.getUserData();
```

Comment: So basically I can do this with a hashmap or some associative array too right?

Comment: then the key would be the attribute name and the value well the value my attribute holds

Comment: Yes, you can store any Objects you want.

Comment: I got to say, the documentation is really bad, dont you think so? I will accept your answer (got to wait a few minutes)

Comment: I really did: how to create custom attributes in javafx. Custom fxml properties javafx. Data attributes javafx. Heck I didnt find anything related to setUserData xD. Im definately doing something wrong haha

Comment: @Asperger Just read the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/toc.htm). All methods are listed there.